# How i can remove directory from Google Index

Tags: google-search-console

after google panda update my site hits so much down.
web master tools  i have to some clone tags and duplicate meta descriptions... general i'm %95 cleaned.

about tags now have some problems. my tags path like this:

```
www.domain.com/tag/apple
www.domain.com/tag/banana
www.domain.com/tag/pear
```

one to one clean so hard.

i did webmaster tools **/tag/** and **/tag** (two option trying) to remove with directory remove to all tags.

robots.txt i wrote:
**Disallow: /tag/**

now google search not show any result. (when i looking site:www.domain.com/tag like this).

but web master tools **Duplicate meta descriptions** still showing this tags (2600 unit). google side showing clean all tags. but web master  site not show all clean. i so much lost visitor about it. how can i fix this problem ?

sorry for my english.

thanks.